# Need to Remove SOQL query from the for loop in code snippet , how to proceed?

Tags: soql

I need to remove soql query from the for loop in below code snippet , how to proceed ?

```java
private static List<IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes> getOtherDealerCodes(Id oppId) {
        List<IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes> listOd= new List<IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes>();
        IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes od = new IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes();
        for(Opportunity_Dealer_Code__c odc:[SELECT Sales_Code_Type__c, Sales_Dealer_Code__c
                                              FROM Opportunity_Dealer_Code__c 
                                             WHERE Opportunity__c = :oppId AND Sales_Code_Type__c = 'Secondary']){
            system.debug('odc====>'+odc);                                     
            User myUser = [select name, email from USER WHERE Rep_Dealer_code__c = :odc.Sales_Dealer_Code__c];
            system.debug('myUser====>'+myUser);
            od.dealerCode = odc.Sales_Code_Type__c;
            od.dealerType = odc.Sales_Dealer_Code__c;
            od.dealerName = myUser.name;
            od.dealerEmailAddress = myUser.email;
            listOd.add(od);        
        }
        return listOd;//
}
```

Will be waiting for your answers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please also consider completing [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) on Trailhead, which covers bulk patterns well, and searching our question history for nearly 1,000 questions that cover bulkification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bulkify the query by using a `WHERE IN` clause in your SOQL so you only make one query.

See example below. Keep in mind that if Rep Dealer Codes aren't unique, you will end up with a problem in your Code-to-User map. But then, you'd also have the same problem in your current code.

```java
private static List<IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes> getOtherDealerCodes(Id oppId) {
    List<IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes> listOd= new List<IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes>();
    IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes od = new IoTQuoteJSON.OtherDealerCodes();

    List<Opportunity_Dealer_Code__c> dealerCodes = getDealerCodes(oppId);
    Map<String, User> dealerCodeToUser = getDealerCodeToUser(getUsers(getSalesDealerCodeSet(dealerCodes)));
    User myUser;

    for(Opportunity_Dealer_Code__c odc : dealerCodes) {
        myUser = dealerCodeToUser.get(odc.Sales_Dealer_Code__c);
        
        od.dealerCode = odc.Sales_Code_Type__c;
        od.dealerType = odc.Sales_Dealer_Code__c;
        od.dealerName = myUser.name;
        od.dealerEmailAddress = myUser.email;

        listOd.add(od);        
    }

    return listOd;
}

private static List<Opportunity_Dealer_Code__c> getDealerCodes(Id oppId) {
    return [
        SELECT Sales_Code_Type__c
            ,Sales_Dealer_Code__c
        FROM Opportunity_Dealer_Code__c 
        WHERE Opportunity__c = :oppId 
            AND Sales_Code_Type__c = 'Secondary'
    ];
}

private static Set<String> getSalesDealerCodeSet(List<Opportunity_Dealer_Code__c> opportunityDealerCodes) {
    Set<String> dealerCodes = new Set<String>();

    for(Opportunity_Dealer_Code__c odc : opportunityDealerCodes) {
        dealerCodes.add(odc.Sales_Dealer_Code__c);
    }

    return dealerCodes;
}

private static List<User> getUsersByDealerCode(Set<String> dealerCodes) {
    return [
        SELECT name, email 
        FROM User
        WHERE Rep_Dealer_code__c IN :dealerCodes
    ];
}

private static Map<String, User> getDealerCodeToUser(List<User> users) {
    Map<String, User> dealerCodeToUser = new Map<String, User>();

    for(User u : users) {
        dealerCodeToUser.put(u.Rep_Dealer_code__c, u);
    }

    return dealerCodeToUser;
}
```